# Implement Jax ws in vertx with spring

Tags: spring-boot, jax-ws, vert.x

I am trying to implement a soap service using jaxws with spring boot and vert.x. I couldn't find any way of doing it directly. Need to wrap ws in vertx. Have anyone faced it and could any one help me guiding to reference. Can we use service discovery in vert.x for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that vert.x is a relevant solution to expose SOAP webservices, it's more appropriate to write Restfull or event based microservices (with the native event bus or a messages broker like Apache Kafka).

If you want to consume a SOAP webservice, I assume that you can use a CXF or Axis client like any java application.

Otherwise I didn't understand the relationship with springboot.